# android - runtime, write list and compare

Tags: android, list, save, runtime

If I use this:

```
try
{
    Runtime.getRuntime().exec("su sqlite3 pm list packages -d");
}
catch (IOException e) 
{
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Where I can write this list? I need compare this list with other items

Comment: Write more description about your question, then only it will easy to answer..

Comment: I need somewhere to write this list and then compare this list with the packagename list